# I have a 2005 Honda Accord EX 5spd 2.4l DOHC. Idle problems

Tags: honda, accord, stall, idle

I began having idle problems , basically after reaching operating temp the vehicle's idle would drop until it stalled . At this point I wasn't getting a CEL . So I checked for air leaks , found none . I then removed the TB and cleaned it, (very little build up)then I inspected the IACV for any build up and it was clean as a whistle. I put the TB back on and performed idle relearn procedure and the vehicle ran great for 3 days, the same idle problem resurfaced, then the CEL came on and I connected my scanner and it read P0505 IDLE AIR SYSTEM MALFUNCTION . I bought a new IACV and replaced it , performed idle relearn procedure and now at cold start the engine idles high (1500-1700) after it reaches operating temperature the idle will drop to 600 and the vehicle will almost stall then it surges to 1200-1500 then drops back down again and just does this over and over again. CEL is on again but the only thing I'm picking up on it is that my EVAP CVS is stuck closed . I could be wrong but I don't believe that that would cause idle problems. Any help would be appreciated and thank you for any info its all welcomed .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you clean the IAC passage when you replaced the valve?

Comment: Yes. Definitely.